# Finding values from another worksheet (a loop in a loop)

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet

I would like to atomatize an excel process using VBA.

The script has to go **cell by cell** in a selected area on Sheet3. Each cell contains a number or is blank. 
The script will go and **search for the value** of each cell in a specific range on Sheet2. When it finds something the content of the whole row where it was found must go **bold.** 
If it finds nothing it will just procede to the next cell.

After browsing here on stackoverflow and different guides I've managed to put together a script. It has no errors but it doesn't do Anything.

---

```
Sub MacroText()
Dim xlRng As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim xlSht As Worksheet
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim iLastRow As Integer
Dim iRow As Integer
Dim bFound As Boolean
Dim xCell As Range
Dim xlCell As Range
Dim valueToFind As String



 bFound = False
Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")
Set xlSht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
Set rng = Selection
Set xlRng = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A:A")

iLastRow = xlSht.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

Set xlRng = xlSht.Range("A1:A" & iLastRow)

For Each xCell In rng
    valueToFind = xCell.Value

    For Each xlCell In xlRng
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
        If xlCell.Value = valueToFind Then
            bFound = True
            iRow = xlCell.Row
            Rows(iRow).Font.Bold = True
            End If


            If bFound = True Then Exit For
            End
    Next xlCell

Next xCell

End Sub
```

---

I am assuming that it has to be something with positioning within the code but I couldn't find any information for that. 
After working on this for 12 hours I would really appreciate your help.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `Find` method to achieve this instead of the second loop

```
Sub MacroText()
    Dim xlRng As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim xlSht As Worksheet
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim iLastRow As Long
    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim bFound As Boolean
    Dim xCell As Range
    Dim xlCell As Range
    Dim valueToFind As String
    Dim FoundRange As Range

    bFound = False
    Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")
    Set xlSht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Set rng = Selection
    Set xlRng = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A:A")

    iLastRow = xlSht.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

    Set xlRng = xlSht.Range("A1:A" & iLastRow)

    For Each xCell In rng
        Set FoundRange = Nothing
        Set FoundRange = xlRng.Find(what:=xCell.Value2)

        If Not FoundRange Is Nothing Then
            FoundRange.EntireRow.Font.Bold = True
        End If

    Next xCell

End Sub
```

Comment: your code will fail if his data starts in another column. excel is fast enough to search through the whole sheet in less than a second, might as well change the range to `"A:XFD"`

Comment: @Banana. Yes it will, however OP's original code used this range. They also may not want to search the whole range.

Comment: @BigBen - There are many ways to write something however I do agree with you about the `Long` (`Integer` is pretty much pointless in VBA). Also, you don't need `Rows` in your line. Have updated

Comment: Nice and elegant solution, Tom. Thank you very much :)

Comment: @Banana thanks for the tip. it is useful for I have data in different columns on each sheet

Answer (score 1):

```
For Each xlCell In xlRng
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
        If xlCell.Value = valueToFind Then
            xlCell.EntireRow.Font.Bold = True
        End If
Next xlCell
```

I don't know what thing you are not getting, but I assumed that you are not getting desired row as bold. Replace the above code with your's for loop and run.
I didn't tested it, but am uncertain about not working.

Comment: thank you for the quick reaction.

at the moment my code does absolutely Nothing. Nor after trying out your snippet.